# Joining two dataframes based on the columns of one of them and the row of another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry if the title doesn't make sense, but wasn't sure how eles to explain it. Here's an example of what i'm talking about

df_1

```
| ID | F\_Name | L\_Name |
|----|---------|---------|
| 0  |         |         |
| 1  |         |         |
| 2  |         |         |
| 3  |         |         |
```

df_2

```
| ID | Name\_Type | Name   |
|----|------------|--------|
| 0  | First      | Bob    |
| 0  | Last       | Smith  |
| 1  | First      | Maria  |
| 1  | Last       | Garcia |
| 2  | First      | Bob    |
| 2  | Last       | Stoops |
| 3  | First      | Joe    |
```

df_3 (result)

```
| ID | F\_Name | L\_Name |
|----|---------|---------|
| 0  | Bob     | Smith   |
| 1  | Maria   | Garcia  |
| 2  | Bob     | Stoops  |
| 3  | Joe     |         |
```

Any and all advice are welcomed! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what you want to do is to reshape your second DataFrame to have the same structure of the first one, right?

You can use [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) method to achieve it:

```
df_3 = df_2.pivot(columns="Name_Type", values="Name")
```

Then, you can rename the index and the columns:

```
df_3 = df_3.rename(columns={"First": "F_Name", "Second": "L_Name"})
df_3.columns.name = None
df_3.index.name = "ID"
```

Comment: okay thanks I think that'll get me to the right track. My next question is what if these tables are part of a larger table, and I want to keep the rest of the tables the same, but only change this part. Then what would I do?

Comment: You mean the rest of the columns? Can the values of these columns be different for the same "F_Name" and "L_Name" combination?

Comment: No they cannot be different, lets say both of the dfs have an age column